# Xml Element SelectNodes help required - C#

Tags: c#, xml, selectnodes

I am new to XML parsing. If anybody can please explain in simple words that what kind of child nodes will be selected from following statement?

```
XmlElement.SelectNodes("child::w:r", nsmgr)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. Why don't you use Linq to XML (XElement) ?

Comment: I have an existing code, which I have to edit. I just need the explanation of the line of code written above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
XmlElement.SelectNodes("child::w:r", nsmgr)
```

Is using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx) overload of the `SelectNodes` method. It should return all child nodes (`child::` axis) of the current element that have an element name `r` in a namespace `w`.

What that namespace `w` is, is defined in the namespace manager `nsmgr`.